# Puppet-Hiera how to give a boolean as default value in hiera_hash?

Tags: variables, puppet, hiera

I am trying to specify a variable which default value should be a boolean.

But none of these things work as I expect them how they should.
If I wanted to have an empty hash as default value I would do it this way:

```
$value = hiera_hash('value', {}),
```

However trying to apply a boolen fails with different errors:

```
$value = hiera_hash('value', {'true'}),
$value = hiera_hash('value', true),
$value = hiera_hash('value', {true}),
$value = hiera_hash('value', {'value' => true}),
```

Actually this line works:

```
$value = hiera_hash('value', true),
```

but fails when using `create_resources()` with `create_resources(): second argument must be a hash`
What would be the correct way to assign true as default value to `$value`?

Comment: If you want to use `create_resources` with the result of your `hiera` call, how can `true` ever be a sane default? How can you use anything but `{}` as your default in this scenario?

Comment: I do not really know what I was trying the other day or how I tried to get things work.

As you said only `{}` makes sense as a default in `hiera_hash` but when generating the resources with `generate_resources()` as a third argument it is possible to pass a default parameter.

It should look like this (it's not tested but I assume that it should work)
`$value = hiera_hash('value', {}),
$value_default = true,
create_resources('value',$value,$value_default) `

Comment: No, the final argument must be a flat hash of `param_name => param_value` pairs. What would you expect the semantics of a `true` default to be, anyway?